# estoy trtando de mostrar una imagen en mi pagina web usando una imagen que esta en mi google drive pues que esta visible para que lo pueda ver todos

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en mi pagina web, la imagen esta en mi Google drive y esta imagen lo puede ver todo el mundo no esta restringida, e usado estas direcciones para ver la imágenes en mi pagina web

https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g

pero no sale la imagen me sale este error

[image: Img]

Comment: Y porque no guardas la imagen en un servidor publico (como el que se usa aqui) y listo?

Comment: por que la persona  que le estoy haciendo la pagina web lo quiere en google drive si no ya lo había echo antes

Comment: ok.. no tengo ni idea como funciona drive, pero te aseguraste de poder verlo por afuera de alguna manera, sin entrar a drive? tu eres el experto.. tal vez sea hora de deciserlo...

Comment: Pero el link que pusistes en tu pregunta tampoco funciona, a mi me da un 404, asegurate de tener  correctamente el link antes que nada , es decir, que se pueda acceder pegado dicho link en la url y que muestre la imagen. Ese es el primer punto

Answer (score 1):

[Antes, anteeeees se podía así](https://codepen.io/jackplug/pen/OPmMJB), pero desde hace unos años Google ya no deja acceder a sus archivos sin una [API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started-php?hl=es-419) o [Librería para tal caso](https://github.com/google/php-photoslibrary).

Peeero, siempre hay formas de saltarse algunas cosas, veamos como se hace esto.

1. El link de tu imagen debe ser el correcto, tu link correcto es el siguiente: https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g

Pero así nomas no lo vas a poder ver con HTML

```html
<img src="https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g" alt="Logo">
```

y Entonces??

2. Cambiamos la forma de acceder a ese recurso (que previamente debe ser de visualización libre como el link anterior) así:

   2.1 Coges el ID del recurso: **1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g**

   2.2. Ese ID lo agregas a este link: **https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=**

   2.3 Resultado: **https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g**

```html
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1PaZEBuHBAbPNVzIUh9Bptgfb_CYEtc6g" alt="Logo">
```

Y listo calixto!!!

---

> Buen hack, pero la imagen será de menor resolución supongo no? ya que miniatura = thumbnail.

Si y no, veamos el siguiente ejemplo: **https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc&export=view&authuser=0**

Esa imagen es grande, pueden verla al dar clic en ella, pero que pasa si la pasamos al **thumbnail**?? Entonces queda el link de referencia así: **https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc=s220?authuser=0**

```html
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc=s220?authuser=0" alt="Tiger">
```

Ven donde pone `s=` en la url?? Bueno pues hace referencia al `size` o tamaño del "thumbnail", y lo pongo entre comillas porque al subir de `size` o tamaño, la calidad del referido "thumbnail" no es que se afecte mucho.

Veamos ahora ese mismo "thumbnail" a tamaño 1024 por ejemplo: **https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc=s1024?authuser=0**

```html
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/0B6wwyazyzml-OGQ3VUo0Z2thdmc=s1024?authuser=0" alt="Tiger">
```

Y la verdad, para ser un "thumbnail", no se ve tan distinto de la imagen original

Comment: Buen hack, pero la imagen sera de menor resolución supongo no? ya que miniatura =  thumbnail.

Comment: Ya te respondo en la pregunta @infinit3Loop__

Comment: Genial!!! pero quita la ultima parte.. es inecesaria y se puede considerar como autopromocion....

Comment: Ok, lo voy a quitar pero justo por eso es que se esta discutiendo últimamente, por preguntas abandonadas y luego dicen ustedes que no se puede hacer nada y si que se puede ordenar el sitio.